# Showing that $\log \log(z)$ is Analytic (Proof Verification)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

**Goal:** Convert $\log \log (z)$ into a single-valued function defined on a suitable region of $\mathbb{C}$ and then prove that it is analytic.

**Attempt:**

1. As has been demonstrated elsewhere, we have that $\log(z)$ is a continuous single-valued function from $\mathbb{C} - (-\infty, 0]$ to $\mathbb{C}$ provided that we restrict $|\operatorname{Im}(\log(z))| < \pi$.
2. Furthermore, consider that for all $z \in \mathbb{C} - (-\infty, 0]$, we have that $\log(z) \notin (-\infty, 0]$.
3. Hence the composition of the single valued function $\log(z)$ with itself produces the well-defined function $\log \log(z)$ on $\varOmega = \mathbb{C} - (-\infty, 0]$.
4. Since the composition of two continuous functions is continuous, we have that $\log \log(z) = w$ is also continuous.
5. We note that the inverse of $\log \log (z)$ is $e^{e^w}$.
6. Then using the notation from calculus we can observe that $\Delta z \rightarrow  0$ implies that $\Delta w \rightarrow 0$. We then have
   $$
   \lim_{\Delta z \to 0} {\Delta w \over \Delta z} = \lim_{\Delta w \to 0} {\Delta w \over \Delta z}
   $$

   so that

   $$
   {dw \over dz} = {1 \over {dz \over dw}} = \underbrace{{1 \over e^w e^w}}_{\text{via the chain rule}} = {1 \over e^{2w}} = {1 \over e^{2 (\log \log(z))}}
   $$
7. We have therefore shown that $\log \log (z)$ is analytic as desired.

Is this proof valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Item 2 is false. With   $\log$ being the principal branch, you have $\log(e^{-1})=-1$, and then you can't use the principal branch again.

This can be fixed by using a different branch at step $1$. That is, let $f(z)=\log(2\pi i+\log z)$ where $\log$ is the principal branch in $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0]$. The imaginary part of $2\pi i+\log z$ is greater than $\pi$, thus the second log can be taken.

Comment: The imaginary part of $2\pi i + \log z$ has to be less than $\pi$ in order for the second log to be taken.

Comment: Couldn't we also change $\varOmega$ from $\mathbb{C} - (-\infty, 0]$ to $\mathbb{C} - (-\infty, 1]$ to fix this problem?

Comment: (1) No, principal branch is defined on $\mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]$ which includes all numbers except those that are real and nonpositive (2) No, then you let $0$ in the domain, which is pretty bad for talking logarithm. @user1770201